# Deduction from negation of uniqueness quantifier

Tags: quantifiers, provability

The problem is this:

By defintion $ \neg(\exists ! y F(x,y))\quad \leftrightarrow \quad \forall y\neg((F(x,y) \wedge \forall z (F(x,z) \rightarrow y=z))) $

I don't see how $\neg F(x,y)\quad \leftrightarrow \quad \exists z (F(x,z)\wedge \neg z = y)$?

Some background for the problem:

This question is from Boolos' The Logic of Provability p.27 where he is going through Peano Arithmetics.

In the question $F(x,y)$ is $\Sigma_{0}$ formula and pseudoterm (i.e. it captures some functions not found in the language of PA).

Obviously $\vdash_{PA}\exists ! y F(x,y)$ (this is the definition of pseudoterm).

Then $ \neg F(x,y)$ should be equivalent to the $\Sigma$ formula
 $\exists z (F(x,z)\wedge \neg z = y)$.

On a intuitive level I feel it's correct but I can't give deduction for it nor can I give waterproof explanation for it.

Comment: You should talk yourself through what's being expressed by that formula. In this case, the opposite of unique existence, is either non-existence (i.e. all things fail the condition), or should there be something which meets the condition (i.e. for some $y$,  $F(x, y)$ holds) then there should be some $z \neq y$ also satisfying the condition.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes you are right about the meaning of the formula. Shouldn't that formula nevertheless be expressed by $\forall y(F(x,y) \rightarrow \exists z (F(x,z) \wedge \neg (z=y)) $? This is equivalent to the first equivalence in my question. I still don't see how am I justified to drop the whole beginning of the formula (that is: $\forall y(F(x,y) \rightarrow $), when expressing just the formula $\neg F(x,y)$ itself.

Answer (score 1):

We have: $∃!yF(x,y)$ that is: $∃y[F(x,y) ∧ ∀z(F(x,z) → y=z))]$.

Thus, assume $∃z(F(x,z) ∧ ¬z=y)$ and assume: $F(x,y)$.

From the first one we get: $F(x,z)$ and $¬z=y$. From $F(x,z)$ and $F(x,y)$, knowing that $∃!yF(x,y),$ we have: $z=y$.

*Contradiction*; thus, we conclude with: $\lnot F(x,y)$.

For the other direction: Assume $\lnot F(x,y)$.

From $∃!yF(x,y),$ we get $F(x,z)$. Now assume $F(x,z) \to z=y$; by *modus ponens* and equality we have: $F(x,y)$.

*Contradiction*; thus, we conclude with $\lnot (F(x,z) \to z=y)$, equivalent to: $(F(x,z) \land \lnot z=y)$.

By $\exists$-intro we get: $∃z(F(x,z) ∧ ¬z=y)$ and we can close the initial $\exists$-elim.